# Goertzel complex signal

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I have a Goertzel algorithm realization in C. And it work correct for not complex signal.

```
float goertzel(int numSamples,int TARGET_FREQUENCY,int SAMPLING_RATE, cufftDoubleComplex* modData,bool Im)
{

    double Z = M_PI * 2. * (double(TARGET_FREQUENCY) / double(SAMPLING_RATE));

    double constantaA = 2 * cos(Z);
    double TMPVAR_v0 = 0;
    double TMPVAR_v1 = 0;
    double TMPVAR_v2 = 0;
    double resultat;

    for(int n =0; n < numSamples; n++) {
        if(!Im)
            TMPVAR_v0 = (modData[n].x + constantaA * TMPVAR_v1 - TMPVAR_v2);
        else
            TMPVAR_v0 = (modData[n].y + constantaA * TMPVAR_v1 - TMPVAR_v2);

        TMPVAR_v2=TMPVAR_v1;
        TMPVAR_v1=TMPVAR_v0;
    }
    resultat = (TMPVAR_v1*TMPVAR_v1 + TMPVAR_v2*TMPVAR_v2 - constantaA * TMPVAR_v1 * TMPVAR_v2);
    return resultat;
    }
```

But i can not understand how i can use it for complex signal.
Please, help me.....

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How doesn't it work correctly?

Comment: The function given here works correctly. How do I transform this function so that I have a complex signal at the input? I don’t understand how the processing of real and imaginary components will differ

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm#Complex_signals_in_real_arithmetic not answer your question? Your question seems to be about the Goertzel algorithm rather than specifically this C code.

Comment: Yes. My question about the Goertzel algorithm. wikipedia not clear for me, in case a complex signal....

Comment: I see. Thx for link:)